# How to read values from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-console, rails-geocoder

I use am using [https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder](http://Geocoder) Gem and when i call: `results = Geocoder.search("McCarren Park, Brooklyn, NY")` my results var look s like here:

```
[#<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x007fc0e6a016e0 @data={"address_components"=>
[{"long_name"=>"McCarren Park", "short_name"=>"McCarren Park", "types"=>["point_of_interest", "establishment"]}, {"long_name"=>"776", "short_name"=>"776", "types"=>["street_number"]}, {"long_name"=>"Lorimer Street", "short_name"=>"Lorimer St", "types"=>["route"]}, {"long_name"=>"Williamsburg", "short_name"=>"Williamsburg", "types"=>["neighborhood", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"Brooklyn", "short_name"=>"Brooklyn", "types"=>["sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"Brooklyn", "short_name"=>"Brooklyn", "types"=>["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"Kings County", "short_name"=>"Kings County", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"New York", "short_name"=>"NY", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"United States", "short_name"=>"US", "types"=>["country", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"11222", "short_name"=>"11222", "types"=>["postal_code"]}], "formatted_address"=>"McCarren Park, 776 Lorimer St, Brooklyn, NY 11222, USA", "geometry"=>{"location"=>{"lat"=>40.7214499, "lng"=>-73.9520707}, "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE", "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>40.72279888029149, "lng"=>-73.95072171970848}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>40.7201009197085, "lng"=>-73.9534196802915}}}, "place_id"=>"ChIJtzAltURZwokRSNfNakChZPU", "types"=>["park", "point_of_interest", "establishment"]}, @cache_hit=nil>]
```

How i can read `lat` and `lng` vars from `results` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrey says, it's an array of hashes, you will need to select the array that has the `lat` and `lng` variables, which seems to be the 'postal_code' hash. Search for a hash where the 'geometry' key is present.

So,

```
location_results = results.data.select{|r| r['geometry']}.first
location_results['geometry']['location']['lat'] # 40.7214499
location_results['geometry']['location']['lng'] # 73.9520707
```

Comment: after first line i have error: **NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x007fc0e25f1450>**

Comment: Ah, right, the array is in the `data` attribute.  I've modified my answer, let me know if that works better...

Answer (score 1):

From [source code](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/lookups/base.rb#L41):

> ```
> # Takes a search string (eg: "Mississippi Coast Coliseumf, Biloxi, MS",
> # "205.128.54.202") for geocoding, or coordinates (latitude, longitude)
> # for reverse geocoding. Returns an array of <tt>Geocoder::Result</tt>s.
> ```

So it is a simple array.

Checkout [this documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/Geocoder/Result/Google) for more info about querying it.

Comment: not working when i try i have this: `NoMethodError: undefined method data for #<Array:0x007fc0e2679d28>`

Comment: @Ponciusz Checkout now please

Comment: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

Comment: @Ponciusz You can either try as edited now, or `results.geometry.location.lng`

Comment: @Ponciusz hm. [how come](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/Geocoder/Result/Google#geometry-instance_method)?

Answer (score 0):

```
result = Geocoder.search("McCarren Park, Brooklyn, NY").first

And then simply call it like this, 
-> result.latitude and  
-> result.longitude
```

But also be sure to check for result, sometimes Geocoder API's response takes more than default specified timeout value and returns nil. So if you face that too, just simply increase timeout value in intializers.

Geocoder::Configuration.timeout = 15 # change 15 to any value that you prefer.

For more references check out https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#advanced-geocoding

Answer (score 0):

```
location_results = results.data.select{|r| r['geometry']}.first
```

and i have now

```
["geometry",
{"location"=>{"lat"=>40.7214499, "lng"=>-73.9520707},
"location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE",
"viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>40.72279888029149, "lng"=>-73.95072171970848},
"southwest"=>{"lat"=>40.7201009197085,
"lng"=>-73.9534196802915}}}]
```

but after this

```
location_results['geometry']['location']['lat']
```

i get again error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```